# Why should I even consider using structs in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct

Is there ever an advantage of declaring a struct in C++? Why shouldn't I just make a class consisting only of data members(i.e. no methods)?

Thanks,

Comment: There's no such thing as "a struct" in C++. There's the `struct` keyword, but it's used to declare a *class*.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's what I was unaware of. Is using the 'struct' keyword simply an alternative way to define a class consisting only of data members?

Comment: Not even. It's "simply an alternative way to define a class", period.

Comment: The only difference is that the default access policy is public instead of private.

Comment: @David I was completely unaware of this. Very interesting.

Comment: Documentation. Many people use `struct` when creating plain aggregate data and `class` when defining business objects and data abstractions etc.

Comment: The standard does talk about a `POD struct`, but it is still just a class.

Comment: I'd say the main reason it is a keyword in C++ is for backwards compatibility with C.

Comment: Instead of complaining, edit your question to be better.  So long as exiting answers remain valid this is ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a POD type where everything is public is saves a line...

```
struct Color {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};
```

vs

```
class Color {
public:
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};
```

And it's also common practice for objects which are just dumb containers of things. Dumb meaning no constructors, operators, methods.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite reason is inheritance. consider this code:

```
class MyClass : public Base1, public virtual Base2 {
public:
    void fun1() override;

private:
    int m1;
};
```

Now consider this very example with a struct:

```
struct MyClass : Base1, virtual Base2 {
    void fun1() override;

private:
    int m1;
};
```

Some say C++ is too verbose, but when checking their code, it look much more like the first example. I find `struct` much easier to read than `class`. In my project I use struct everywhere.

The question you should ask is "Why should I even consider using classes in C++?", because IMO, struct are the same but less verbose.